# Django: Dots in slug don't work in DetailView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, slug, detailview

I'm modelling genome assemblies whose names often contain a dot (.)
I wrote a DetailView which **works for names without dots** but noth names with dots. I get this error:

```
404 - Using the URLconf defined in genomeDBmanager.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: ...
```

My model:

```
class Assembly(models.Model):
    ...
    identifier = models.SlugField('unique identifier', max_length=50, unique=True)
    ...
```

My view.py:

```
class AssemblyDetailView(DetailView):
    slug_field = 'identifier'
    template_name = 'overview/assembly.html'
    model = Assembly
    context_object_name = 'assembly'
```

My overview/urls.py:

```
app_name = 'overview'
urlpatterns = [
...
    path('assembly/<slug>/', views.AssemblyDetailView.as_view(), name='assembly-detail')
]
```

This URL works: `127.0.0.1:8000/strain/SomeAssembly-1`, this one doesn't: `127.0.0.1:8000/strain/SomeAssembly.2`.

Comment: As far as I know, this *is* not a valid slug.

Comment: ... but it worked! Do you mean the part <slug> should be <slug:identifier>?
I tried this and it didn't work. I think it changed with Django 2.2. You have to specify the slug in `view.py`
#edit: I just noticed that <slug> suffices. Changed the question accordingly.

Comment: no, you can use another path converter, like `str`, or `path`. But again, that is not a slug. A slug is not supposed to have dots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: this is correct behavior for a slug, since a slug is not supposed to have dots.

A *slug* simply does not allow dots in the slug. Indeed, if we [**`slugify(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) for example `'foo.bar'`, we get:

```
>>> from django.utils.text import slugify
>>> slugify('foo.bar')
'foobar'
```

It is therefore absolutely valid to *not* accept dots. It thus means that the `SlugField` of your model, likely does not slugify the title (or whatever is "slugified") correctly.

You can accept `str`ings, and `path`s with the `str` and `path` path converters, as is specified in the [documentation on *path converters* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#path-converters):

> - `str` - Matches any **non-empty string**, excluding the path separator, `'/'`. This is the default if a converter isn’t included in
>     the expression.
>
> (..)
>
> - `path` - Matches any **non-empty string, including the path separator, `'/'`**. This allows you to match against a complete URL
>     path rather than just a segment of a URL path as with `str`.

So you can specify for example:

```
path('assembly/<str:slug>/', views.AssemblyDetailView.as_view(), name='assembly-detail')
```

but again, this is *not* a slug.

Comment: @FatTony: no, the idea of a slug is usually to make "nice looking" urls. As in, without percent encoding, but a dot is not percent encoded. It will work, I'm only saying that it is part of the specs to not accept a dot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the default slug-regex doesn't accept dots. The solution is to specify one using re_path like this:

```
re_path(r'^assembly/(?P<slug>[0-9a-zA-Z.\-_ ]+)/$', views.AssemblyDetailView.as_view(), name='assembly-detail')
```

Everything else works the same.